# Postgresql via homebrew vs. mountain lion OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, rails-postgresql

This is bothering me to no end.

I'm setting up a Rails 3.2 environment with Postgresql on my Mac with OS 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).

I basically followed the directions in the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql), and installed postgresql version 9.2.0 via Homebrew. but whenever I do

```
which psql
```

and

```
psql --version
```

it always shows me the location and version of the system postgresql that came preinstalled with Mountain Lion (`/usr/bin/psql` and version 9.1.4, respectively), rather than the location and version of the Postgresql that I installed with Homebrew (`/usr/local/bin` and version 9.2.0, respectively).

I also set up a Launch Agent, so that postgresql automatically starts up when I start the system.

I've even tried following the directions from this [blog](http://metacog.tumblr.com/post/28333408639/setting-up-a-development-environment-on-mountain-lion), and I still get the same results when I run `which psql`.

However, when I do:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

I receive the following results:

```
501   556   120   0 Fri02AM ??         0:00.12 /usr/local/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

Does this mean that I'm running the homebrew version of postgresql?

Do I have to uninstall the system postgresql?

Comment: I posted a guide on how to install postgres on Lion here: http://astonj.com/tech/how-to-install-postgresql-on-mac-os-x it may work for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by adding directory path (/usr/local/bin) to the config file,                                                                                                                                 `~/.bash_profile`  you will get resolve the above issue.

to know more [refer this link.](http://www.jonathandean.com/2011/08/postgresql-8-4-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/)

Comment: Be sure to add /usr/local/bin in front of /usr/bin

Answer (score 12):

Another option would be to use Heroku's Postgres.app, I personally find this a bit easier to setup and manage.

http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: I really liked the Postgres.app, it was VERY fast to get up and running, I was having some frustration with homebrew and installing it on my dev box, this did the trick! Seriously, very fast to get running.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Postgres.app from Heroku**, by adding

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

to ~/.bash_profile, it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your ~/.bash_profile

I think this works for when you install Postgres via Homebrew